# Add user claims in identityserver4

Tags: identityserver4

I have created identityserver4 project and tried to add more claims after user log in. Here is my code

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model)
       {
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {
            // validate username/password against in-memory store
                 CoreDb.Models.User user = null;
                 if (( user = await _userService.VerifyUser(model.Username, model.Password)) != null)
            {
               // var user = _users.FindByUsername(model.Username);
                await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.Name, user.Id.ToString(), user.Name));

                // only set explicit expiration here if user chooses "remember me". 
                // otherwise we rely upon expiration configured in cookie middleware.
                   var props = new AuthenticationProperties();
                   if (AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin && model.RememberLogin)
              {
                            props.IsPersistent = true;
                            props.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration);
              };

                    props.Items.Add("scheme", AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName);

                    // issue authentication cookie with subject ID and username
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id.ToString(), user.Name, "idp", props, _userService.GetUserClaims(user).ToArray());

                    //IEnumerable<ClaimsIdentity> claimsIdentity = null;
                    //var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(_userService.GetUserClaims(user), CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    //await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));

                    // make sure the returnUrl is still valid, and if so redirect back to authorize endpoint or a local page
                    if (_interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(model.ReturnUrl) || Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                    }

                    return Redirect("~/");
                 }

                    await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(model.Username, "invalid credentials"));

                    ModelState.AddModelError("", AccountOptions.InvalidCredentialsErrorMessage);
          }
```

However, I do not see my claims for the user when I call my api in requirement handler although my user id is there. What is an appropriate way to add user claims?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claims must be added to the response context. If you are using aspnetidentity then the following approach will work for you

Ensure to include ProfileService implementation and hook up to IdentityServer at ConfigureServices

```
 .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

---

```
 private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory;
```

---

In the GetProfileDataAsync, you can include your new claims

```
 /// <summary>
    /// This method is called whenever claims about the user are requested (e.g. during token creation or via the userinfo endpoint)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        var principal = await claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);
        //context.AddFilteredClaims(principal.Claims);
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(principal.Claims);            
        context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("IP Address", coreOperations.GetCurrentRequestIPAddress()));

    }
```

Comment: I found the problem. I need to add UserClaim  Types in ApiResource definition. Otherwise, IdentityServer4 will filter any claims I added in HttpContext.SignInAsync.

Comment: The method you proposed is probably similar to adding user claims during login. I will try this when I have time.

Comment: I tried the ProfileService. It seems that it works for ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials grantType.

Comment: happen to know this today, with the latest version, you will need to include the claims to apiresource scopes, then your profile service being called.. means your request must be from a client with a scope that has claims interested in.

Comment: What is the `claimsFactory` in the above answer?

Answer (score 1):

As Jay already mentioned, you can write your own ProfileService. If you don't use aspnetidentity you can just add the Claims in the Login method and add these lines to the GetProfileDataAsync Method of your ProfileService:

```
 List<Claim> claims = context.Subject.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Role).ToList();

  context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
```